# LinkedIn special Characters

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I've tried to post an LinkedIn update with Json in .Net. Everything works fine until i use an special character. If i post "Financiën" to the API i get an "Bad Request". I've tried to htmlencode and urlencode but then i see the encoded version as an update. Has somebody solved this?

This is the request that fails:

```
{"comment":"Financiën","visibility":{"code":"anyone"}}
```

And this works:

```
{"comment":"Financien","visibility":{"code":"anyone"}}
```

Comment: What error do you get back? Can you check if it's tied to encoding? How do you encode your request? What encoding does the remote endpoint accept?

Comment: bad request, that's the only thing i get back. It's valid Json with no encoding. What the remote accepts i do not know, in the LinkedIn documentation i cannot find anything.

Comment: No encoding sounds a little bit weird, you have to have a way to specify how bytes are to be mapped to characters. Can we safely assume you mean you are using an agreed standard that is likely to be UTF8?

Comment: i don't give a explicit encoding, that's right. It's just a WebClient request with an UploadString.

Comment: after adding client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; still an error

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer, Linkedin needs encoding Encoding.ASCII for a post.